# Remote app service declaration gets removed from package.appxmanifest when trying to create appx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I created my appxmanifest according to [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/communicate-with-a-remote-app-service), so it looks something like this:

```
<Application ...>
       ...
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
      <uap3:AppService Name="com.myapp.service" SupportsRemoteSystems="true"/>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Application>
```

And I added `uap3` definition to the `Package` tag.

It works fine when I deploy the app to my PC and my phone using Visual Studio. But when I try to create an appx package (in both modes, sideload and for store) in either Release or Debug configuration, it removes the `Extension` from my `package.appxmanifest`.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, using SDK version 14393. (Min version is also set to 14393)

Why visual studio keeps removing my remote app service definition from my manifest file? How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried **AppServicesProvider** in [App services sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices)? I've tested with this sample and it worked well in my side. After creating appx package, the `Extension` still exists in ***Package.appxmanifest***.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I took a look at the sample. It works fine, but then I added `remoteSystem` uap3 capability to the manifest too. Then, first time I created an appx, it worked fine. Then I created an appx for the *second time*, the `Extension` went away. Then to confirm it, I extracted the original version again and did exact same steps, and got same result. Can you check if you can reproduce it in your machine too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue now. I'd suppose the problem here is because you've checked **"Automatically increment"** or changed **Version** manually in **Create App Packages** wizard.

[Package version number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering) is set as a value in the **Version** attribute of the **Package/Identity** element in ***Package.appxmanifest*** like:

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap3">

    <Identity
      Name="Microsoft.SDKSamples.AppServicesProvider.CS"
      Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
      Version="1.0.0.0" />
  ...
</Package>
```

If we checked **"Automatically increment"** or changed **Version** manually in **Create App Packages** wizard.
[image]

Visual Studio will update ***Package.appxmanifest*** automatically. And in this scenario, `uap3:AppService` element will be removed too. I will report this issue internally and update here if there is any progress.

For now, as a workaround, please **do not** checke **"Automatically increment"** or change **Version** manually in **Create App Packages** wizard. If you need to change the package version, you can do it manually in ***Package.appxmanifest***.

Comment: Hmm, so it was the effect of *second time*, not remote system capability. Thanks for the workaround, hopefully this gets fixed in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need SupportsRemoteSystems you can change the `uap3:AppService` to `uap:AppService` and then VS doesn't delete it.